# Excel date to day from sheet name

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm using this code to grab the sheet name and put it into cell C2.

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```

I would like cell C1 to display the correct day of the week (ddd) depending on the date set in cell C2 / Sheet name

Adding =C2 into C1 and changing the cell format to "custom" "ddd" does not work. It just displays the date as it's written on the sheet name.

Ideas?

Comment: =Text(weekday(C2,1),"dddd") This formula will display the name of the weekday, Weekday(C2,1) will extract the day number starting from Sunday as 1 and Text will convert it to full day name

Comment: What is the date value in C2?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the "DATE" you are pulling from C2 is actualy a TEXT.
If you select the cell `C2` with this "DATE" and apply "General" formatting, what do you see?

- Nothing changed >> Text
- Whole number >> Date value
- Decimal number less than or equal to 1 >> Time value
- Decimal number something like 42719,7724475694 >> Date and Time value

### Convert Date stored as Text to Date (serial number)

To convert a Text/String to Date, you can use the `DATEVALUE` [function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252).

> The DATEVALUE function converts a date that is stored as text to a serial number that Excel recognizes as a date. For example, the formula =DATEVALUE("1/1/2008") returns 39448, the serial number of the date 1/1/2008.

If you then use "ddd" number format, you should see the name of the day.